# Linking to the internet

Tags: wireless

I know nothing about computers.
I'm trying to link to my wireless and it is asking for SSID and BSSID.
What is this and where do I find it.

Answer (score 2):

The [Service set identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSID) (SSID) is just the name of your wireless network. The router needs to give a human-readable name so you can find it, especially in crowded areas like an apartment building.

Your best bet is to check out a video like [this one on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJvB97cmrWk), which visually explains how to connect.

Basically, you should be moving your mouse to the upper right of your screen to a little antenna-looking thing, and selecting your WiFi network from the list that drops down when you click the icon. The only thing you may need to type is the password to connect to your wireless network if it's encrypted (it should be, but leave that for another day). Good luck and don't get frustrated. Try YouTube for other related videos. It's often better than just trying to do a web search and reading lots of results. Especially when you are just starting out with Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1):

SSID is a name identification for wireless networks, as per my example, the SSID for my network is 'TCT-LOCAL'. That one, you have to check your modem for.

If you are asking to find out what the 'WEP' is, that answer is the same: check your modem. You may also want to call your Internet Service Provider.

The rest should be configured more-or-less automatically as long as you have those two, but it's important to note that having wireless on your laptop means you can connect via Wi-Fi, like you would for wiring a regular computer to a modem for internet.